# (beets) configuration error: import must be a collection, not NoneType

Tags: python, configuration-files

I post it there, because I could only find an answer in the beets mailing-list, there: http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.audio.beets.user/cutoff=173

What does the following lines mean:

```
$ beet import /home/music
configuration error: import must be a collection, not NoneType
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Adrian Sampson  for this answer:

> This means that your configuration file contains a line like this:
>
> ```
> import:
> ```
>
> all alone, with nothing under it. In YAML, that means "set the config option called `import` to null". You probably meant to do something like this:
>
> ```
> import:
>     copy: no
>     write: no
> ```
>
> Maybe you accidentally added a blank line, or failed to indent the following lines?